# What kind of robots will be sent to Mars with the first Starships(s)? (ex BFR)

Tags: spacex, mars, spacex-starship, robotic-missions

Elon Musk has recently announced plans to send two unmanned Starships to Mars in 2022. If the timeline is met, what robots will be sent? As I understand, the tasks will be

> [...] landing two cargo missions on the red planet by 2022, [SpaceX] hopes to be able to confirm sources of water and potential hazards by that time. SpaceX also plans to start building mining, power and life support infrastructure that year [...]

[[source]](https://www.engadget.com/2017/09/29/spacex-mars-bfr/)

These ambitions definitely need thorough preparation themselves, maybe just as much as Starship and Super Heavy. Take for example the Mars rovers: they required much more development time. And that was just for cruising around and communicating outputs of cameras and other instruments.

Is there any information out there about what kind of robots will be used, and whether SpaceX intends to develop them itself or to buy them?

Comment: If the robots should be ready for a mission in 2022, they should be in development now.

Comment: Musk's announcements and SpaceX's activities don't always align. If the mission happens, information will be available, until then it is pointless speculation.